# Get the first matched number between square brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like the following `woocommerce_click_and_pick_shipping_branch[1]`, and I want to use regEx to get the number between the square bracket.

I've tried the following with no luck:

`replace([^\[\]]+)(?=\]\[[^\]]+\]$)`

Comment: Do you want the first digit (e.g. 1 in 123) or number (e.g. 123)? If you want the whole number, then: `s.replace(/^[^\[]*\[|\].*$/g,'')` will do the job. It will get the first set of characters between `[ ]` in the string.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following:

```
var str = "woocommerce_click_and_pick_shipping_branch[14432]".match(/\[(\d*)\]/);

if (str) {
  console.log(str[1]); // 14432
}
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ydm1wkd6/)

Comment: The last line should guard against no matches, so something like: `console.log(str? str[1] : '')`.

Comment: More concise idea: `console.log(str && str[1]);`

Comment: @TheIronDeveloper—that's an option, but it will return either *null* or a string, which are different Types.

Comment: It ends up being more helpful when you use it as a variable, where you can add a guarded conditional: `var value = (str && str[1]) || '';`

Comment: @TheIronDeveloper—no longer quite so concise, and `var value = str? str[1] : ''` is equivalent. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3cm7321x/1
This will loop through your string and when it finds an integer the `if` statement is `true` and it will return you the number.

```
var str= "woocommerce_click_and_pick_shipping_branch[1234]";
var number="";
for (i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] % 1 === 0){
        number +=str[i]; 
    }
}

alert(number);
```

Comment: This doesn't work when there are numbers outside of the square brackets. http://jsfiddle.net/1stuf6o0/

Comment: @JoshCrozier You are right, did not think that through. It is a solution if there are only numbers between brackets :)...